# How can I give a different tag every time I call Get.toNamed

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes

Even if it is the same page, it contains different data, so there are pages that need to be given different controllers. So I'm solving it by giving the tag value to the page and the controller.

So I made a global controller and I'm using the tag value

```
class GlobalController extends GetxService {
  int tag = 0;
  
  String getTag() {
    return "${tag++}";
  }
}
```

like this

And I used it like

```
goToPage() async {
    final tag = _globalController.getTag();
    Get.to(() => Page(tag), binding: PageBinding(tag));
}
```

The problem is, I think that this way doesn't look very good, and it's complicated. So I want to use GetPage, instantiate page routing, and change the tag value every time I callback.
However, GetPage is a static variable and cannot give a changing tag value.

Is there any way to solve it?